# Azerothcore - ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'acore'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: azerothcore

I have tried for hours to get around this.

I can confirm the database is running, the tables are there, the user 'acore' is created, the password is set correctly and the user has permissions to the acore_auth, world and characters tables, yet no matter what I do, the db_assembler.sh script refuses to run, claiming that the user acore has been denied access.

[Heidi SQL Screenshot showing acore user permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mziOa.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

A prior step in the instructions refers to copying the config.sh file from /azerothcore/conf/dist to /azerothcore/conf and amending it as needed for any SQL information different from the default (I was using port 3308 instead of port 3306). I did that and amended the new config.sh file however the db_assembler.sh script was still looking at the config.sh file in the /azerothcore/conf/dist directory (which had the default settings of 3306).

When I amended THAT file, the import worked perfectly.